# VDBench: Raw device 'sd=sd1,lun=/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0sx' does not exist, or no permissions

Tags: testing, io

I'm not sure what the cause of this is. I am running vdbench in Admin mode in Powershell, and specifically typing `./vdbench -f example1`. However `./vdbench -t` works. What could be the reason for this?

I tried to run the default sample, and it worked. However it is not the same given any actual parameter file.